# Laravel 5 null cookie crash

Tags: php, laravel

Scenario:

Same browser.

1. Tab 1: logging into my laravel application.
2. Tab 2: logging into my laravel application.
3. Tab 2: log off
4. Tab 1: Click a button that causes a redirect to a route that's protected by: Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
   ...

Result: Laravel 5 crashes before it gets to my code on:

[image]

Stack:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException Call to a member function setCookie() on null
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:184 __construct
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:131 fatalExceptionFromError
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:116 handleShutdown
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:0 addCookieToResponse
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:72 handle
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:125 Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:36 handle
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:125 Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:40 handle
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:125 Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:42 handle
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:125 Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:101 call_user_func:{/home/vagrant/dev/opus-web-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:101}
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:101 then
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:115 sendRequestThroughRouter
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:84 handle
    public/index.php:53 {main}
    public/index.php:0 [main]
```

Even when I remove the Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'] group from my routes... going in tab 1 to the now open URLs will produce this error. I just don't get it.

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: using Laravel version 5.0.33

Comment: Can you show the whole routing.php file? I can't reproduce your error... I'm redirected to the login page in the first tab.

Comment: the problems occurs deep in laravel. BEFORE the routing. Even when I take away the Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'] ...   I get the same error when even trying to go to an open url.

Comment: Yes, that I know: it happens in the middle of the global middleware stack.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your middleware? Are you applying middleware in any of your controllers or just at a route level? It sounds like your returning data somewhere before the response is returned, hence the null error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that the problem is your logic in the check of the CSRF.

Here is the problem:
You are checking if the tokens match, and that function is as follow:

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    $token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');

    if (! $token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
        $token = $this->encrypter->decrypt($header);
    }

    return Str::equals($request->session()->token(), $token);
}
```

But if you look closely you will see that in the return it checks for:

```
$request->session()->token()
```

But, the session is `null` so you will get an exception for trying to request a method from a null.

So, if I'm not mistaken, all you need to do is just to add an additional check to the if in the `handle` method.
Instead of this:

```
if ($request && ((
      $this->isReading($request) 
      || $this->excludedRoutes($request) 
      || ($this->tokensMatch($request) && Auth::check())
    )))
```

You should have this:

```
if ($request && ((
      $this->isReading($request) 
      || $this->excludedRoutes($request) 
      || ($request->hasSession() && $this->tokensMatch($request) && Auth::check())
   )))
```

This way, if there is no session it will not even check if tokens match and it will not crash there.

You may also consider refactor that part of the if statement to a function that by name it describes what you are checking for, and even the complete if statement to a function that says it all. Just for code clarity.

---

Is either that, or you may consider checking your other Middlewares, anyone that be touching the headers of the request and potentially be unsetting the headers.

If you take at the code of the `handle` function of the StartSession Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $this->sessionHandled = true;
    if ($this->sessionConfigured())
    {
        $session = $this->startSession($request);
        $request->setSession($session);
    }

    // ** HERE ALL OTHER MIDDLEWARES ARE BEING CALL
    $response = $next($request);

    if ($this->sessionConfigured())
    {
        $this->storeCurrentUrl($request, $session);
        $this->collectGarbage($session);
        // ** AFTER ALL OTHER MIDDLEWARES ARE CALLED THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION 
        // TOUCHES THE HEADER AND IS NULL
        $this->addCookieToResponse($response, $session);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

So, it is possible that somewhere in any of any other middleware you are touching the header and leaving it null, as per your error says.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the cause, but I'm just not sure about it. Hoping one of you will know.

In kernel.php:

I had the `'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'` defined in the `$middleware` black and not the `$routeMiddleware`. when I moved it to the `$routeMiddleware` I stopped getting that error.

Content of VerifyCsrfToken:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request && (($this->isReading($request) || $this->excludedRoutes($request) || ($this->tokensMatch($request) && Auth::check()))))
        {
            return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
        }

        return view('sessionOver');
    }

    protected function excludedRoutes($request)
    {
        $routes = [
            'deployPush'  // webhook push for bitBucket.
        ];

        foreach($routes as $route)
            if ($request->is($route))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be dangerous.  I'd guess it works now because it's no longer being loaded globally which is something it should be doing.  Otherwise it could be opening you up to a CSRF attack.

Comment: I installed laravel 5.0.33 to reproduce the error but I can't, did you give us more details ( routes.php, ... ). And why you need the code inside the `handle()` of your `VerifyCsrfToken` Middleware because I it's the origin of the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will usefull for you .check in middleware some think similar like this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    if ( ! Auth::user()) // Your logic here...
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');

    return $response;
}
```

Ref::https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/disable-global-verifycsrftoken-and-use-as-middleware-doesnt-work-setcookie-on-null

in that discussion some cookie error discussed.that might help you

Answer (score 0):

Experienced a similar issue specifically when returning a response from a middleware, and I realised it was caused by returning `return view('my.view.blade')` rather than `return response()->view('my.view.blade')`.

So in short, don't return the view directly. Chain the `view()` helper to the `response()` helper.

```
return view('myview.blade'); //wrong
return response()->view('myview.blade'); //works
```

Comment: In that case, the blade is not being rendered. What do you suggest?